# Bash script runs from successfully from command line but not when invoked by program

Tags: bash, file-permissions

I have a script "postprocessing.sh". This script is suppossed to be used for the post-processing of the data ouput of a thermo-hydraulic simulation package, called by a parent program called "npo".

The code below is suppossed to find a data-vector "CFVALU_10000202" in the data file "MELC.PTF" write the data-vector to a file "DATA1", perform a little simple post-processing and finally write the result to "ext.goal1".

To that end a lot of the functions used (MREAD, write g0.s0, essentially everything written to aptplot1.gr) a part of a plotting-tool installed in a different part of the file tree. We invoke this plotting tool when calling aptbatch.sh with aptplot1.gr as input argument. The path to aptbatch.sh is saved in the path variable of the ".bashrc"-file.

When executing the script below from bash by typing either "./postprocessing.sh" or "bash postprocessing", it does **exactly** as expected. The files DATA1, aptplot1.gr and ext.goal1 are produced in the current working directory with the correct content.

When running "npo" the program, that calls "postprocessing.sh", aptplot1.gr is written to file but neither "DATA1" nor "ext.goal1" is produced. The program stalls when trying to call "aptbatch.sh". Trying experimentally to run "postprocessing.sh" without using "aptbatch.sh", just writing a set of random variables to file works fine, so the problem is not in calling the post-processing script.

According to the author of npo the program should just issue a system command with the name of the script, invoking the command shell.

I tried looking into permissions for the executables involved and applied chmod +x to anything and everything but no dice. Can anyone think of a system variable or permission right that could result in this?

```
#! /bin/sh
cd ~/Melcor/NordicBWR/MinGoalFct/NordicBWR_05_08

# clean up
rm -f aptplot1* ext.goal1 DATA1*

# write read out commands for data vector to file
echo " MELCOR 0 PTF \"MELC.PTF\"" > aptplot1.gr
echo " MREAD 0 \"CFVALU_10000202\" DONE" >> aptplot1.gr
echo " write g0.s0 FILE \"./DATA1\"" >> aptplot1.gr
# execute file
aptbatch.sh -batch aptplot1.gr -nosafe -hardcopy

# postprocessing of max. data value
awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($2>max) max=$2} {GF = max-10000} {if (GF<0) GF=10000-max} END {printf("%6.5f\n", GF ) } ' DATA1 > "ext.goal1"
```

Summary:

Script runs fine from command line, script stalls at aptbatch.sh when called by program (but works fine even in this case, without the aptbatch.sh call). Path to aptbatch.sh is in the .bashrc, when running "aptbatch.sh -batch aptplot1.gr -nosafe -hardcopy" using an aptplot1.gr produced during a failed run, it works fine.

Ideas?

Comment: Is it run in the same directory? (probably a non issue wince the first line is a CD). PATH would matter since it has to find aptbatch.sh somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on the suggestion by @John3136, try putting the full path to `aptbatch.sh`, e.g. `/home/scripts/aptbatch.sh`, instead of just the name. If it's not in the `$PATH` of whatever shell is executing the script, it won't be found.

Comment: Well, that was embarrassingly simple for something I wasted half my weekend on. Thank you both. For future reference is there any environmental variable I can look up, which will tell me which shell is used?

Answer (score 0):

on un*x (as opposed to e.g. w32), the current path is usually *not* searched for programs.
only those paths in the `PATH` variable are searched.

so as a first, try to give a search-path for your script. it doesn't need to be absolute, relative will do just fine. the following will run the script in the *current* directory (as denoted by `./`)

```
 ./aptbatch.sh -batch aptplot1.gr -nosafe -hardcopy
```

if your script is somewhere else, then it *might* be that your PATH variable is different for an interactive shell and when run as a script.ö

try running

```
  echo $PATH
```

both in your script and on the cmdline, to see whether they are different.
(probably do `echo $PATH >> /tmp/debug.txt` in the script, so you can inspect the file `/tmp/debug.txt` after the script was executed.